# Factoring a topological universal cover

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a compact, connected, locally path-connected, and semilocally simply connected topological group with $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $u\colon \widetilde{X}\to X$ be its topological universal cover, which also has the structure of a topological group.

Let $Y$ be a locally path-connected topological *space*.

Suppose there exists a surjective, local homeomorphism $f\colon \widetilde{X}\to Y$ and a (surjective) morphism $a\colon Y \to X$ of topological spaces with connected fibers such that $u = a\circ f$.

Thus, one could say that the universal cover $u$ ''factors'' through $f$ and $a$.

**Question.** With these above conditions, can one deduce that $Y$ is a topological *group*?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "morphism $Y\to X$"? morphism of what?

Comment: @KevinCasto $X$ is a group by assumption (I agree the notation is misleading).

Comment: It easily follows from the assumptions that $a$ is bijective.

Comment: @YCor Sorry about that! I meant a morphism of topological spaces

Comment: @user44191 what you prove is what I just said, namely that $a$ is bijective. A little more step is needed to obtain that $a$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The topology of $Y$ is finer than that of $X$.  But the topology of $\tilde{X}/{\mathbb Z}$ is finer than that of $Y$.  However, $\tilde{X}/{\mathbb Z}$ is nothing but $X$.  So $X$ and $Y$ should be homeomorphic, or am I missing something?

Comment: @user43326 I believe this this should work, but I am a bit confused about how you show that the topology of $\tilde{X}/\mathbb{Z}$ is finer than that of $Y$? Could you expand on this point?

Comment: Since there is a continuous map from one to the other...

Comment: Or, you can simply use the classification of coverings.